# A Murder Most Foul: Alicia Adams

Tags: word-problem, mystery

Forgive me if this matches an existing murder mystery. I tried to search before writing this one up

---

Outside the office building, sirens wailed and flashing lights illuminated the snow covered ground. Inside, a troop of police officers were milling about, gathering clues and investigating the scene.

Just inside the door, behind the secretary's desk, lay a dead body. The body was that of the poor secretary, Alicia Adams. It appears that Alicia was working late, transcribing some documents into her computer when the assailant came in and shot her twice, once in the head and again in the chest.

On the stand next to her monitor was the original document she was transcribing, and a word processor was visible on the screen. The document on the screen showed :

```
...We need to meet our quodkhe6rthgfvbn
```

It appears that, after she had been shot she had hit her head once on the keyboard, thus the garbled letters.

Now, security logs show three people in the office at that time:

```
Byron Baker - The CEO
Cindy Chase - The CFO
Darryl Davis - The CIO
```

After taking the three into custody and recording their statements, the police couldn't determine who would have killed the secretary. They did find that any of the three would have adequate motive, as the secretary was moving to blow the whistle on a major scam the three were pulling.

After a few days, the case started going cold. So, the force brought in a detective from a neighboring precinct. After reviewing the case files, including Alicia's exemplary reviews and skills analyses, she told the officers to make an arrest.

**Who killed Alicia, and how did the detective know?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was

> Cindy Chase - The CFO

Because

> DKHE6 is a keyboard shifted version of CINDY
> D is above C
> K is below I
> H is above N
> E is above D
> 6 is above Y

In addition,

> If we can presume that Cindy did, in fact, hit her head on the keyboard, then that explains the rest of the mess at the end: rthgfvbn

More supporting evidence:

> If Alicia was really as awesome as she appears to be, she would known that typing "CINDY" on the screen might have been noticed by the murderer. She might have even thrown herself forward to ensure her head hit the keyboard and thus leading Cindy to assume the entire mess was from the head impact and not a clue.

Comment: I like the reasoning you give for the `more supporting evidence`. I was more going for the fact that her hands shifted up a row and she was typing the name without seeing it. Of course, that would only work if I hadn't typoed the `K` which should have actually been an `8` in that scenario.

Comment: I wondered about the almost-patter. An exemplary keyboardist doesn't need to look and can tell where the home keys are by touch. Most keyboard have a touch feature on the F and J for exactly that reason. Am I right about the mess at the end or is there something else missing?

Comment: Nope, you are spot on for the mess at the end. It was mostly there to try and mask the letters in the middle. As for the touch feature on the home row, she did just get shot. I would think she might miss the fact that there are tiny raised features on the letters. One of those aspects for me to fine tune for future puzzles!

Comment: What's the significance of the quo at the start, then ??

Comment: @Ditto I think that's the beginning of the word "quota" as in the phrase "meet our quota"

Comment: @EngineerToast, that is correct. Again, just trying to mask the glaringly obvious clue.

Comment: I'd make a lousy detective :(

Comment: @tfitzger For what it's worth, I don't think it's obvious. Meeting quotas is a common thing in my world so I automatically assumed that the gibberish started *after* `quo`. After that, I guessed at some kind of keyboard pattern and got lucky in noticing the pattern. Alicia was a heck of a secretary.